# What does "forget by the bedside" and "from where" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> He forgot by the bedside the strange book from where his prayers were
>   read.

Does it mean:

Lying on bed, He forgot the strange book. This book is the one which he read his prayers from?

I'm not sure if "forget by the bedside" means that "as he sleeps on the bed, he forgot the book", or "he forgot the book when he was next to the bed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying that there is a strange book that he reads prayers from, and that he forgot this book and left it lying beside his bed (maybe on a table next to the bed, or on the floor, etc).

The phrase ***"forgot by the bedside the strange book"*** might be easier to understand if you expanded it into the equivalent sentence ***"forgot about the book and left it by the bedside"***.

The phrase ***"from where"*** is a prepostional phrase that indicates ***where*** he reads his prayers ***from*** (the strange book).

Comment: I don't understand how he "forgot and left it". Does it mean that after he put the book beside his bed, he forgot (maybe stopped thinking about?) the book?

Comment: For example, maybe he was going to church and needed to remember to take the prayer book with him. But he forgot to bring it, and left it on the table beside his bed.